# CLLocation: how many observations are needed to get Speed in IOS

Tags: swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

Apple and [others](https://www.cumulations.com/blogs/41/CalculatingSpeedfromCoordinatesiniOS) on the web recommend you get the speed using Core Location through the delegate method `didUpdateLocations` using some version of:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *updatelocation = locations.lastObject;
    double speed = updatelocation.speed;
    speed = speed * 1.94384;     //converting speed from m/s to knots(unit)
    NSLog(@"Speed %f",speed);
}
```

However, to save power, [Apple also recommends](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/LocationBestPractices.html) you call stopUpdatingLocations in the didUpdate method:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    // Get a fix on the user's location
    ...

        // Stop location updates
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

I am finding that when I call stopUpdatingLocations the speed gets stuck frequently on zero so it always shows zero. If I remove the `stopUpdating` line, the speed works properly. It appears that more than one observation is needed to get an accurate speed or at least immediately calling `stopUpdatingLocations` in the method prevents  getting reliable speed readings.

The app doesn't always have to know the speed.  It just should supply an accurate reading when the user requests it.

Can anyone suggest a working approach that gets an accurate speed reading at an acceptable level of of power use?

Comment: Calling `startUpdatingLocation` and then `stopUpdatingLocation` in the `didUpdateLocations` delegate method is a bad idea. If you need a one time location update, use `requestLocation` which was designed to provide just that.

Comment: Does requestLocation come with Location.speed?  And is the speed likely to be accurate?

Comment: `requestLocation` also delivers its update through the `didUpdateLocations` delegate method, so yes, it should come with a `speed` measurement too. As for the accuracy of that, I cannot tell, since I haven't used it myself for speed measurements, you'll have to experiment with that.

Comment: Ok.  I'll test it out!  Thx!